# update mysqli query on ajax form submit

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I have a dynamicaly php page that displays all results from database and i want to create a search bar that updates at every character the user inputs.
My problem is that i can't make the query update! he always displays no results. First I had the query in the same page as the form but that wouldnt work because the ajax would run all the code from the page when i used that url in the parameters so i splitted everything but it still doesnt work. Any sugestions?

PHP page - part with search bar --> categorias.php:

```
<div class="container">
<h2 class="title">Empresas De Confianza</h2>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-centered">
        <form method="POST" action="buscador.php" id="search">
            <input class="search-bar" type="text" name="filterName" id="filterName">
            <button type="submit" hidden></button>
            <?php
            $msqliquery = "SELECT * FROM empresa WHERE categorias_id = $id AND menulogo IS NOT NULL";
            $array = $connection->query($msqliquery);
            ?>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


<?php
echo '<div class="row index-margin" id="results">';

if (mysqli_num_rows($array) == 0) {
    echo "<h2 class='text-center'>No hemos encontrado ningún resultado con esa busqueda!</h2><ul class='text-center'><li class='list-categorias'><a class='fa-categorias fa fa-refresh' href='categorias.php?id=$id'></a></li></ul>";
};
while ($field = mysqli_fetch_array($array)) {
    ?>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 parent size">
        <a style="background-color:<?php echo $field['color'] ?>"
           href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $field['id'] ?>">
            <img src="/test<?php echo $field['menulogo'] ?>" class="logo img-grayscale">
            <div class="hover-item"><h5 class="label-profile"><?php echo $field['nombre'] ?></h5></div>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php }
echo '</div>' ?>
```

´
Form/search bar handling --> buscador.php:

```
<?php
require 'config.php';
$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

$filterName = $_POST['filterName'];
$msqliquery = "SELECT * FROM empresa WHERE categorias_id = $id AND menulogo 
IS NOT NULL AND nombre COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%$filterName%'";
$array = $connection->query($msqliquery);
```

Function for update at every character and ajax form submit:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var timeoutID = null;

    $('#filterName').keyup(function (e) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        timeoutID = setTimeout(searchEmpresa.bind(undefined, e.target.value), 500);
    });

    function searchEmpresa(str) {
        console.log('search: ' + str);
        $("#search").submit(function (event) {
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: 'buscador.php',
                data: $("#filterName").val(),
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $("#results").load("categorias.php #results > *");
                }
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: What is the Error you are getting ?

Comment: it always returns no results...

Answer (score 0):

You have to send data as object with key value pairs

```
data: {filterName:$("#filterName").val()},
```

Also you have to correct method: 'post', So you should have method of posting not type of posting
Hope it will help you.

put this code in your buscador.php

```
<?php

if (mysqli_num_rows($array) == 0) {
echo "<h2 class='text-center'>No hemos encontrado ningún resultado con esa 
busqueda!</h2><ul class='text-center'><li class='list-categorias'><a 
class='fa-categorias fa fa-refresh' href='categorias.php?id=$id'></a></li>
</ul>";
};
 while ($field = mysqli_fetch_array($array)) {
 ?>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 parent size">
    <a style="background-color:<?php echo $field['color'] ?>"
       href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $field['id'] ?>">
        <img src="/test<?php echo $field['menulogo'] ?>" class="logo img-
  grayscale">
        <div class="hover-item"><h5 class="label-profile"><?php echo 
 $field['nombre'] ?></h5></div>
    </a>
  </div>
 <?php }
echo '</div>' ?>
```

and append it to your div with id result

$('#result').append(data);

Comment: Now the ajax works on the first div created and it displays it but with no content. empty div and the others stay there from the initial query..
The page is this if it helps seing it: https://www.esdeconfianza.com/categorias.php?id=2

Comment: check what result are you getting in your console and paste it here

Comment: I don't get any console errors thats the thing! the only thing in my console is the console.log{}

Comment: check your console please and tell me the response you are getting, there should be some data that is coming in response.because you are doing console.log(data). So it should show you some result if it is getting it from your php file

Comment: one more thing that you are not returning or echoing any value in your php file. so you have to return the array value like this. return $array; or var_dump($array) so you will surely get the result

Comment: it doesnt have any response from that log. 
only the first one. it displays search: 'input'.
After dumping the array it went to buscador,php and displayed this:
object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(18) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: so you have to use mysql_fetch_assoc to fetch the data as you have one result from database.. num_rows showing 1 result. check your query in db that how many rows are you getting in running the query into database.

Comment: change mysqli_fetch_array to mysqli_fetch_assoc?

Comment: not a fetching problem , the query you are using is giving you only one row from database containing 18 rows. check your query. All is fine

Comment: the problem is that it doesnt display it.
it updates the div but it doesnt fill it with content.

Comment: you dont have any code in your ajax response to append it to div, what code are you using to append the result.

Comment: reloading the div #results where the results from the query are displayed. Thought as the query changed reloading the div would change content. Maybe not?

Comment: Progress! Now it displays the content but ajax isn't working

Comment: change $("#search").submit(function (event) to $("#search").click(function () and make your input type="button" so you dont need any event prevention.So ajax will also work on click

Comment: i aaplied those changes and nothing happened. the behavior is the same. it displays the results in buscador.php

Comment: what is the result in your console and check if you have set the div with id="result" because we have to append the return response with result id

Comment: i cant check console because on submit it redirects me to buscador.php
the id's are all set

Comment: dear you dont need to submit if your using ajax why you are submitting your data.... you may have some error.share your skype I can resolve the issue over skype.

Comment: we changed from submit function to click.. therefore its not gonna submit on its own?
@Serrano653

Comment: i tested changing back to submit and when i submitted it actually displayed the results in the same page as expected but the other results didnt leave which makes sence because i have the initial query in categorias.php.
maybe do a if(empty($_POST['filterName']))?